# Generating amCharts graphics with php

Tags: php, mysql, amcharts

I'm using amCharts to generate graphics.
Follow the step-by-step them to generate a graph from a MySql query.

My query is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, idpartner, date, eventtype FROM vpnconnectionlog
        WHERE name = 'treinamento-12345678'
        ORDER BY date";
```

I wanted to understand how to make the x-axis is based on the "eventtype" which may be true or false and the y-axis is based on the date.

Y-axis with the date I got doing `"category Field", "date", "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD"` but I could not managed to get x relative to eventtype, true or false... What can I do?

```
{"eventtype":"false","date":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"true","date":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"false","date":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"true","date":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"false","date":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"false","date":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"true","date":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"false","date":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"true","date":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"true","date":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"false","date":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"true","date":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"false","date":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"true","date":"2016-09-02 00:00:00"},{"eventtype":"false","date":"2016-09-02 00:00:00"}]
```

Comment: So... your valueField isn't working? Could you append example data, so it's easier to understand?

Comment: @gerric Ok... I edited my post.

Comment: Ok. First of all AmCharts needs the value to be numeric, so you have to convert your boolean strings into e.g. 0s and 1s. Next your dates have duplicates(, which is probably nonsense for your usecase). How do you want the booleans to be displayed? As serial chart? What have you tried?

Comment: @gerric Can we start a chat? 
So it would be better to talk than I get editing the post.

Comment: Sure. Just post the room link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122673/discussion-between-cesar-and-gerric).

Comment: @gerric I created the room.